# is there a word which describes someone who confidently believes it's better to not dwell on some things?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I.e. maybe they have questioned something in the past, realized it was fruitless, and now take the stance that even asking or thinking about the question is not worth their time, because they believe it's impossible to know.

For instance, does free will exist? Does God exist, etc.

The term agnostic is close for the god question, but that word I believe conveys more of uncertainty of the answer rather than confidence in knowing that the question is not even worth thinking about.

Comment: Quora  says it is rhetorical questions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I have the perfect answer for this, but let me try.

> A [practicalist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/practicalist) - an advocate or adherent of what is practical.

I also thought about the words `realist` and `conformist` but I think they get as close to what you described as the word `practicalist` does.

This is if course ignoring the perfectly correct answer you mentioned `agnostic` because not many use it that way and a lot confuse it:

> "agnostic, agnosticism". OED Online, 3rd ed. Oxford University Press. September 2012. agnostic. : A. n[oun]. :# A person who believes that nothing is known or can be known of immaterial things, especially of the existence or nature of God.